# How do I build a Cacher in Rust without relying on the Copy trait?

Tags: hashmap, rust

I am trying to implement a `Cacher` as mentioned in [Chapter 13](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch13-01-closures.html#limitations-of-the-cacher-implementation) of the Rust book and running into trouble.

My `Cacher` code looks like:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub struct Cacher<T, K, V>
where
    T: Fn(K) -> V,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<K, V>,
}

impl<T, K: Eq + Hash, V> Cacher<T, K, V>
where
    T: Fn(K) -> V,
{
    pub fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, K, V> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn value(&mut self, k: K) -> &V {
        let result = self.values.get(&k);
        match result {
            Some(v) => {
                return v;
            }
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(k);
                self.values.insert(k, v);
                &v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my test case for this lib looks like:

```
mod cacher;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use cacher::Cacher;

    #[test]
    fn repeated_runs_same() {
        let mut cacher = Cacher::new(|x| x);
        let run1 = cacher.value(5);
        let run2 = cacher.value(7);

        assert_ne!(run1, run2);
    }
}
```

I ran into the following problems when running my test case:

1. `error[E0499]: cannot borrow cacher as mutable more than once at a time`
   Each time I make a run1, run2 value it is trying to borrow `cacher` as a mutable borrow. I don't understand why it is borrowing at all - I thought `cacher.value()` should be returning a reference to the item that is stored in the `cacher` which is not a borrow.
2. `error[E0597]: v does not live long enough` pointing to the v I return in the None case of value(). How do I properly move the `v` into the `HashMap` and give it the same lifetime as the `HashMap`? Clearly the lifetime is expiring as it returns, but I want to just return a reference to it to use as the return from value().
3. `error[E0502]: cannot borrow`self.values`as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable` in value(). `self.values.get(&k)` is an immutable borrow and `self.values.insert(k,v)` is a mutable borrow - though I thought `.get()` was an immutable borrow and `.insert()` was a transfer of ownership.

and a few other errors related to moving which I should be able to handle separately. These are much more fundamental errors that indicate I have misunderstood the idea of ownership in Rust, yet rereading the segment of the book doesn't make clear to me what I missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there a quite a few issues to look into here:

First, for the definition of the function `value(&mut self, k: K) -> &V` ; the compiler will insert the lifetimes for you so that it becomes `value(&'a mut self, k: K) -> &'a V`. This means, the lifetime of the `self` cannot shrink for the sake of the function, because there is reference coming out of the function with the same lifetime, and will live for as long as the scope. Since it is a mutable reference, you cannot borrow it again. Hence the error `error[E0499]: cannot borrow cacher as mutable more than once at a time`.

Second, you call the `calculation` function that returns the value within some inner scope of the function `value()` and then you return the reference to it, which is not possible. You expect the reference to  live longer than the the referent. Hence the error  `error[E0597]: v does not live long enough`

The third error is a bit involved. You see, `let result = self.values.get(&k);` as mentioned in the first statement, causes `k` to be held immutably till the end of the function. `result` returned will live for as long  your function `value()`, which means you cannot take a borrow(mutable) in the same scope, giving the error
`error[E0502]: cannot borrow self.values as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable in value() self.values.get(&k)`

Your `K` needs to be a `Clone`, reason being `k` will be moved into the function `calculation`, rendering it unusable during `insert`.

So with `K` as a `Clone`, the `Cacher` implementation will be:

```
impl<T, K: Eq + Hash + Clone, V> Cacher<T, K, V>
where
    T: Fn(K) -> V,
{
    pub fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, K, V> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: hash_map::HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn value(&mut self, k: K) -> &V {
        if self.values.contains_key(&k) {
            return &self.values[&k];
        }

        self.values.insert(k.clone(), (self.calculation)(k.clone()));
        self.values.get(&k).unwrap()
    }
}
```

This lifetimes here are based on the branching control flow. The `if self.values.contains_key ...` block always returns, hence the code after `if` block can only be executed when `if self.values.contains_key ...` is `false`. The tiny scope created for `if` condition, will only live within the condition check, i.e reference taken (and returned) for `if self.values.contains_key(...`  will go away with this tiny scope.

For more please refer [NLL RFC](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/nll-rfc/blob/master/0000-nonlexical-lifetimes.md)

As mentioned by @jmb in his answer, for your test to work, `V` will need to be a `Clone` (`impl <... V:Clone> Cacher<T, K, V>`) to return by value  or use shared ownership like `Rc` to avoid the cloning cost.

eg.

```
fn value(&mut self, k: K) -> V  { ..
fn value(&mut self, k: K) -> Rc<V> { ..
```

Comment: With Rc (_not allowed yet to comment on @jmb's answer_):   https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3b9f2f67ce57a22583d68511295b2ecb

Comment: Thanks Vikram. Could I get a little more detail on the test case itself? I tried to implement it without using Rc(for familiarity with the language) but got the double mutable borrow problem again. Considering it only takes the reference to the V it shouldn't be a problem.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4f8846f6349e4c1e1dbb9b9b4b4c36fa

Comment: @WarSame, Yes, the function signature of `value()` on its own is fine, but to work in tandem with your `test`, it is not. (as explained). I see, you have already declared  `V` to be a `Clone` type, so why not change the signature to `fn value(&mut self, k: K) -> V  { ..`  ? since you don't want want to use `Rc`.  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=c342786e2300ab66ed0b716448b30548.

Comment: @WarSame, Another way could be to use raw pointers. This will allow you to keep the signature of `value()` intact and `V` is not required to be a `Clone` type. Note that usage of raw pointers is generally considered "unsafe", but if strictly speaking of this particular case, it seems fine. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=27f5ff5691ac5e0b8e6cc151a676577e

Comment: Thanks Vikram. I am brand new to Rust and have not played around with cloning or many different elements yet. I appreciate your patient explanations and the extra detail/options you present. I would definitely prefer to avoid raw pointers because I am aware they can be very dangerous. I switched to the Clone method and it works!

Answer (score 2):

1. Returning a reference to a value is the same thing as borrowing that value. Since that value is owned by the cacher, it implicitly borrows the cacher too. This makes sense: if you take a reference to a value inside the cacher then destroy the cacher, what happens to your reference? Note also that if you modify the cacher (e.g. by inserting a new element), this could reallocate the storage, which would invalidate any references to values stored inside.

   You need your values to be at least `Clone` so that `Cacher::value` can return by value instead of by reference. You can use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) if your values are too expensive to clone and you are ok with all callers getting the same instance.
2. The naive way to get the instance that was stored in the `HashMap` as opposed to the temporary you allocated to build it would be to call `self.values.get (k).unwrap()` after inserting the value in the map. In order to avoid the cost of computing twice the location of the value in the map, you can use the [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) interface:

   ```
   pub fn value(&mut self, k: K) -> Rc<V> {
       self.values.entry (&k).or_insert_with (|| Rc::new (self.calculation (k)))
   }
   ```
3. I believe my answer to point 2 also solves this point.

Comment: Your code does not compile at all. Please fix that!