# Is is possible to implement the same method in different ways for different traits using generics?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

For an exercise in the Rust book involving closures and generics, I'm trying to implement a method on a struct `Cacher` that can take a value  of virtually any type; perform an operation on it and store the result in a `HashMap` where the value is the key and the result is the value, so that, in case of expensive operations, next time value comes along the result is already at hand in the `HashMap`.

After much struggling of lifetimes and ownership, I came up with the idea of differentiating just a little bit the code, depending on whether value is a scalar / implements `Copy` trait or a complex heap-stored `Clone` type.

It solved the ownership problems, but now the compiler is giving an error because the two versions of the method have the same name.

Is it forbidden to overload methods in Rust? How can I solve the issue otherwise (since naming the method differently based on the type of value kind of defeats the very purpose of implementing generics)?

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]

use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Cacher<'a, T, V>
where
    T: Fn(V) -> V,
    V: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: HashMap<V, V>,
}

impl<'a, T, V> Cacher<'a, T, V>
where
    T: Fn(V) -> V,
    V: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<'a, T, V> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            value: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T, V> Cacher<'a, T, V>
where
    T: Fn(V) -> V,
    V: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + Copy,
{
    fn value(&'a mut self, newVal: V) -> &'a V {
        let k = newVal;
        match self.value.get(newVal) {
            Some(res) => res,
            None => {
                self.value.insert(newVal, (self.calculation)(&newVal));
                self.value.get(k).unwrap()
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T, W> Cacher<'a, T, W>
where
    T: Fn(W) -> W,
    W: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    fn value(&'a mut self, newVal: W) -> &'a W {
        let k = newVal.clone();
        match self.value.get(&newVal) {
            Some(res) => res,
            None => {
                let res = (self.calculation)(newVal);
                self.value.insert(&k, res);
                self.value.get(k)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let op = |val| val;

    let mut c = Cacher::new(op);
    let v = 5;

    println!("{} -> {}", v, c.value(&v));
}
```

```
error[E0592]: duplicate definitions with name `value`
  --> src/main.rs:32:5
   |
32 | /     fn value(&'a mut self, newVal: V) -> &'a V {
33 | |         let k = newVal;
34 | |         match self.value.get(newVal) {
35 | |             Some(res) => res,
...  |
40 | |         }
41 | |     }
   | |_____^ duplicate definitions for `value`
...
49 | /     fn value(&'a mut self, newVal: W) -> &'a W {
50 | |         let k = newVal.clone();
51 | |         match self.value.get(&newVal) {
52 | |             Some(res) => res,
...  |
58 | |         }
59 | |     }
   | |_____- other definition for `value`
```

Comment: *Is it forbidden to overload methods in Rust?* — already answered: [How do I use parameter overloading or optional parameters in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24936872/155423)

Comment: Other people asking about this exercise: [How do I build a Cacher in Rust without relying on the Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53331382/155423); [How do I remove excessive `clone` calls from a struct that caches arbitrary results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46388977/155423)

Comment: *depending on whether value [...] implements `Copy` trait or a complex heap-stored `Clone` type* — this is not a useful distinction. Anything that implements `Copy` also implements `Clone`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you! The answers that were previously given for this exercise were very enlightening, however there's something that still bugs me, if I can borrow a bit more of your attention. I understand that in the daisy-chaining self.values.get() and self.values.insert() there are borroings happening of values because get has &self implicit paramenter and insert has &mut self. But I'm not sure I fully understand the sense of holding up those borrowings for the whole scope block. Meaning: I'd expect the result of get() to be held, while the intermediate borrowing of values to be released